# Morphia - custom field with custom reader and writer

Tags: java, morphia

I want to add a custom type of field that will have a default behaviour.
my purpose is to handle all type of secret fields:

for example:
I have password field on user class, and I want password field to be encrypted on some way, so instead of:

```
  @Entity
    public static class User {
        String name;
        String pwd;
        String pwdToken
        public User() {
        }
        public User( string name, string password ) {
            super();
            this.pwd = password;
        }
    }
```

and then managing the decrypt and encrypt from outside - service or controller

I would have something like that:

```
  @Entity
    public static class User {
        String name;
        SecretField pwd;
       
        public User() {
        }
        public User( string name, string password ) {
            super();
               this.name = name;
            // this.pwd.set(password)
        }
    }

   public final class SecretField implements Serializable {
    
      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  
      private String encryptedContent;
      private String token;
    
     public SecretField(String content) {
               this.token = generateToken();
               this.encryptedContent = decrypt(content, this.token);
     }

     // when especially called the decrypted pwd will be returned
     public decrypt(){
        decrypt(encryptedContent, token)
     }  

     //here I should override the default output object - return this.encryptedContent instead of whole object
     //???
     
   }
```

This way, every time I have a secret field I can just use this class and the encrypting will be done automatically, And I won't need to manage the on each controller seperatly.
On update and insert, the password will be sent as decrypted string from client and on get the enrypted string will be returned.

Is it possible with morphia?

Answer (score 1):

You can write a custom codec in 2.0 to do that for you.  Prior to that you could write a life cycle event handler to do that.  The docs for that can be found at https://morphia.dev